# Log4j2 on Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, log4j2

I've been debugging the whole day and almost tried everything what the internet say about how to do it but I still don't get it correctly.

I am using Spring Boot and log4j2 for my logging because I want my logs to be written on a file instead of console. When I start Spring Boot, the log file is successfully created but I can't see "Hello Philippines" written on the file. I hope you can help me guys with this one.

Here is my Spring Boot Application:

[image]

My log4j2.xml

[image]

My POM:

[image]

I don't have any on my application.properties, this is the result when I run my application:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name of your logger in the log4j2.xml is com.example but the logger you create in your application is DemoApplication.

You should create your logger like this:

```
Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DemoApplication.class);
```